# Cannot resolve symbol n method

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, resolve

i'm creating android app which use camera. I have problems with some methods. For example:

```
camera = Camera.open(cameraID); - cannot resolve method 'open(int)'
camera.takePicture(null, null, this); - cannot resolve method 'takePicture'
```

i've got similar problems [ camera.release(); etc. ] I was trying to import android.hardware.camera2; but it does not help

any ideas to resolve ?

Comment: but import android.hardware.Camera; is deprecated.

Comment: so which i should use ?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the older android.hardware.Camera API, so make sure you have imported it with

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
```

Even though it is deprecated, it continues to work just fine, and is necessary for using the camera on pre-Lollipop (API21) devices.

Answer (score 0):

Camera2 api is only available since Android Lollipop (api 21). Make sure you have set you `targetSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` file to at least 21.